# Original German for Goethe quote "By seeking and blundering we learn."

Tags: translation

This quote has been attributed to Johann Wolfgang von Goethe,
for example, at [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/16242-by-seeking-and-blundering-we-learn).

> "By seeking and blundering we learn."

I would appreciate seeing the original German.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick search yielded two relevant results:

> 1. Auch ist das Suchen und Irren gut, denn durch Suchen und Irren lernt man.
>      (Goethe, J. W., Gespräche. Mit Johann Peter Eckermann u.a., 1. Mai 1825)
> 2. Irrend lernt man.
>      (Goethe, J. W., Briefe. An August von Goethe, 14. Januar 1814)

Comment: Ich häng mal die Quelle auf. https://www.aphorismen.de/suche?f_thema=Lernen&f_autor=1461_Johann+Wolfgang+von+Goethe

Comment: Thanks! And is "blundering" a reasonable translation for "Irren"?

Comment: I think "to irr" is to rare a word.

Comment: @dan Danke fürs Anhängen.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: "Irren" has two meanings - 1. to err, to make a mistake, and 2. to wander (without aim or orientation) - usually in the form "umherirren". The proximity to "Suchen" implies that Goethe went for the second meaning, and "blundering" seems like a reasonable translation.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I would not consider it a reasonable translation. I am not a native English speaker, but my gut feeling would connote a kind of carelessness or foolishness in 'blunder', while 'sich irren' is a rather neutral description of being wrong. I would rather have translated the quote with 'By seeking and being mistaken, we learn.'

Comment: [Link zum Gespräch für Zitat 1](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Goethe,+Johann+Wolfgang/Gespr%C3%A4che/%5BZu+den+Gespr%C3%A4chen%5D/1825). [Link zum Brief für Zitat 2](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Goethe,+Johann+Wolfgang/Briefe/1814)

Comment: (to) err, (to) be mistaken, (to) be wrong, or (to) make mistakes are more suitable translations than (to) blunder.

Comment: @Florian: The problem is that none of your choices are as pithy as "blundering."  (And Goethe was pithy!) I appreciate your point, but likely "blundering" will remain on the web as *the* translation.

Comment: @Joseph, „seeking“ isn’t pithy either and we’re fine with it. The problem with blunder is that it includes a sense of carelessness that’s not in the original. It also doesn’t respect the connotation of going amiss, which forms the contrast to seek. In my eyes, (to) err matches best: it’s rare enough to be pithy and combines the original meanings of being wrong and lost best.

Comment: @Florian: Good point! "By seeking and erring we learn."